# mySQL Quickly Delete Lots of Rows

Tags: mysql, select, sql-delete

I have two tables, I need all rows from the first that don't appear in the second.

The tables can be destroyed as they're dumps from other tables.

First table has ~57million rows. Second table has ~10million rows.

Both of these queries are taking forever for obvious reasons, please help me do this quicker.

```
SELECT *
FROM db.first
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM db.second)
```

```
DELETE FROM db.first
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM db.second)
```

Edit: I don't need any records from the second table, I only need rows that appear in the first table that don't appear in the second table.

Comment: Do the `DELETE` first, THEN do the `SELECT`.  At least that way you're not doing the same comparisons twice.

Comment: Do you have indices on these tables?

Comment: @Paul Sonier: No, tables are not indexed.

Comment: @Jeff:  Well, there's your problem right there.  Indexing your tables will speed things up considerably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be a lot quicker using joins:

```
select one.*
from db.first one
left join db.second two on one.id = two.id
where two.id is null
```

and the delete:

```
delete first
from first 
join second on first.id = second.id
```

Comment: I don't need any records from the second table. I just need all the rows from the first table that don't appear in the second.

Comment: @Jeff right.. the `select` example above gets you just that... the LEFT JOIN is used to exclude (not include) the records from the second table (see `where two.id is null`). The `delete` example deletes anything in the first table that exists in the second table, which would leave the first table matching what you want.  I based it off of the 2 queries you listed.   It appears you may lack experience with joins and should take a look here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html